# Can an android app run gradle ? How?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm currently trying to generate apk files in offline mode using an android app, and I don't understand how this is possible.

This application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=fr creates projects, and inside these projects there are gradle files (build.gradle, settings.gradle, ...). (This application can generate apk when we are offline)

I tried to make these files in a new project on my computer and to generate an apk and it worked, thanks to gradle.

But now, I'm asking myself how do this app manage to use gradle? Do we just have to put gradle in a file on the device, and then use a command to execute it?

We probably don't have permissions, do we?

I don't know how to do it in Java, and I don't know if this is the right way to do it.